# Highcharts Mysql Json arrays PHP

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, highcharts

I am trying to get the right Json output for my highchart scatter plot, see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/rma6j77t/3/).

Json output that i want:

```
[{
        "name": "Female",
        "color": "red",
        "data": [{
            "name": "Anna",
            "x": 161.2,
            "y": 51.6
        }, {
            "name": "Clair",
            "x": 167.5,
            "y": 59.0
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "Male",
        "color": "blue",
        "data": [{
            "name": "James",
            "x": 174.0,
            "y": 65.6
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "Peet",
        "color": "black",
        "data": [{
            "name": "Peet",
            "x": 175.3,
            "y": 71.8
        }]
    }
]
```

data.php

```
<?php

$arr    = array();
$arr1   = array();
$arr2   = array();
$result = array();

$sql = "SELECT `gender`, `name`, `length`, `weight`
            FROM `highcharts_data`
            WHERE `gender` = 'Female'";
$q   = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
$arr['name'] = 'Female';
$arr['data'] = array([(float)$row['length'], (float)$row['weight']]);
$arr['color'] = 'red';

array_push($result,$arr);
}

$sql1 = "SELECT `gender`, `name`, `length`, `weight`
            FROM `highcharts_data`
            WHERE `gender` = 'Male' AND `name` != 'Peet'";
$q1  = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql1);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q1)){
$arr1['name'] = 'Male';
$arr1['data'] = array([(float)$row['length'], (float)$row['weight']]);
$arr1['color'] = 'blue';

array_push($result,$arr1);
}

$sql2 = "SELECT `gender`, `name`, `length`, `weight`
            FROM `highcharts_data`
            WHERE `gender` = 'Male' AND `name` = 'Peet'";
$q2  = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql2);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q2)){
$arr2['name'] = 'Peet';
$arr2['data'] = array([(float)$row['length'], (float)$row['weight']]);
$arr2['color'] = 'black';

array_push($result,$arr2);
}

print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Json output that i get:

```
[{
    "name": "Female",
    "data": [
        [161.2, 51.6]
    ],
    "color": "red"
}, {
    "name": "Female",
    "data": [
        [167.5, 59]
    ],
    "color": "red"
}, {
    "name": "Male",
    "data": [
        [174, 65.6]
    ],
    "color": "blue"
}, {
    "name": "Peet",
    "data": [
        [175.3, 71.8]
    ],
    "color": "black"
}]
```

Can someone tell me how to change the data.php file, so I get the correct Json output!

Thanks!

Comment: data: [{name: 'Anna',x: 161.2,y: 51.6}, in this where u getting the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of how you can format the PHP into JSON. This does not include the mysql part, but that should **not** be hard to figure out.

**Updated 2017/10/12, corrected mistake with double data**:

**Updated 2017/10/16, corrected mistake without array push**:

```
<?php
$males   = array();
$malepersons = array();
$females = array();
$femalepersons = array();
$result  = array();

$values = [[
    "name" => 'Anna',
    "height" => 175,
    "weight" => 53.4,
    "gender" => 'Female'
    ],[
    "name" => 'Dan',
    "height" => 185.1,
    "weight" => 90.4,
    "gender" => 'Male'
    ] ];

//Simplified for loop
foreach ($values as $row){
    $person = array();
    $person['name'] = $row['name'];
    $person['x'] = $row['height'];
    $person['y'] = $row['weight'];

    if($row['gender'] == 'Male'){
        array_push($malepersons, $person);        
    } elseif($row['gender'] == 'Female') {
        array_push($femalepersons, $person);
    }
}

//took these out of the for loop, only need to be set once
$males['color'] = 'black'; 
$males['name'] = 'Male';
$males['data'] = $malepersons;
$females['color'] = 'green';
$females['name'] = 'Female';
$females['data'] = $femalepersons;


array_push($result, $males);
array_push($result, $females);
print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
?>
```

This will give you JSON that looks like this:

```
[{
  "color": "black",
  "name": "Male",
  "data": [{
    "name": "Dan",
    "x": 185.1,
    "y": 90.4
  }]
}, {
  "color": "green",
  "name": "Female",
  "data": [{
    "name": "Anna",
    "x": 175,
    "y": 53.4
  }]
}]
```

Which is what highcharts wants as series input.

In your case, the `$values` array is actually the data returned by SQL, you just need to change the loop to loop what you want it to loop.

**Added working example**: https://ideone.com/RPp3DO

**PHP DOCS on keyed arrays**: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Hi Ewolden, thanks for your quick response! It's close to what I have in mind. In your Json output "data" is mentioned two times. This is not working in the example file. I am an absolute beginner in the field of php and Json. I have made a start with the following data.php file (next post) but this is the output i get so far: `[{"color":"black","name":"Male","data":{"name":"Peet","data":{"x":175.3,"y":71.8}}},{"color":"green","name":"Female","data":{"name":"Clair","data":{"x":167.5,"y":59}}}]`.

Comment: Part1: `<?php
$result = array();
$sql = "SELECT `gender`, `name`, `length`, `weight`
FROM `highcharts_data`";
$q  = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
    $person = array();
    if($row['gender'] == 'Male'){
        $person['name'] = $row['name'];
        $person['data'] = ['x' => $row['length'], 'y' => $row['weight']];
        $males['color'] = 'black';
        $males['name'] = 'Male';
        $males['data'] = $person;
}`

Comment: elseif($row['gender'] == 'Female') {
        $person['name'] = $row['name'];
        $person['data'] = ['x' => $row['length'], 'y' => $row['weight']];
        $females['color'] = 'green';
        $females['name'] = 'Female';
        $females['data'] = $person;
    }
}
array_push($result, $males);
array_push($result, $females);
print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>

Comment: thanks again! The output is displayed in the correct way, but there is a missing part. Currently I have two groups, namely Female and Male. I miss the third group "Peet". Where I want to have this person separate from the other groups. Can you add this in your example. I will also add a new answer containing the changes I've made so far.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a part. The loop does not work. I get only data for one person while I expect data from two persons as in my example. Can you also look at this part.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to find out why I only get one person per group, while there are two people per group. So in data two people must be displayed and not one person. I have adjusted your preview so that you can see that only the last person per group is visible. See https://ideone.com/uuqAIk

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks again for your help and time! I will update the correct answer.

Comment: I am new at this forum. What is the correct way to give your answer as correctly?